# CVE Identifier for PuTTY vulnerability?

Tags: cisco

The PuTTY version 0.66.0.0 I have on my computer can supposedly be exploited, allowing remote servers to perform a DoS attack or execute arbitrary code. I'm sure it's because PSCP is missing a bounds check for a stack buffer when  processing the SCP-SINK file size response to a download request, but I'm having trouble finding the CVE identifier for this vulnerability. Could you please help me find it?

This is my first time posting so sorry if there's anything I did wrong.

Comment: Do you have a question? This is the wrong site for announcements.

Comment: Just updated it; I'm trying to find the CVE Identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply look at the [PuTTY home page](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/). It has all the information and links. It would have been much, much faster for you if you had done a simple search. It took less than a second for me to find it.

> **summary**: Vulnerability: old-style scp downloads may allow remote code execution
>   **class**: vulnerability: This is a security vulnerability.
>   **difficulty**: fun: Just needs tuits, and not many of them.
>   **priority**: high: This should be fixed in the next release.
>   **present-in**: 0.66
>   **fixed-in**: 0.67 [bc6c15ab5f636e05b7e91883f0031a7e06117947](https://git.tartarus.org/?p=simon/putty.git;a=commitdiff;h=bc6c15ab5f636e05b7e91883f0031a7e06117947)
>
> Many versions of PSCP prior to 0.67 have a stack corruption
>   vulnerability in their treatment of the 'sink' direction (i.e.
>   downloading from server to client) of the old-style SCP protocol.
>
> In order for this vulnerability to be exploited, the user must connect
>   to a malicious server and attempt to download any file.
>
> (Note however that the vulnerability kicks in after host key
>   verification, so the host key of the server has to have been accepted
>   to get this far.)
>
> This vulnerability only arises in the old SCP protocol, so you can
>   work around it in a vulnerable PSCP by using the -sftp option to force
>   the use of the newer SFTP protocol, provided your server supports that
>   protocol.
>
> This bug was discovered by [tintinweb](https://github.com/tintinweb/pub/tree/master/pocs/) and has been assigned CVE ID
>   [CVE-2016-2563](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2016-2563).
>
> *Vulnerability details*: Prior to any download in the SCP sink protocol, the server sends a line of text consisting of an octal
>   number encoding Unix file permissions, a decimal number encoding the
>   file size, and the file name. Since the file size can exceed 232
>   bytes, and in some compilation configurations of PuTTY the host
>   platform's largest integer type is only 32 bits wide, PuTTY extracts
>   the decimal file size into a temporary string variable to send to its
>   own 64-bit decimal decoding function. Unfortunately, that extraction
>   was done carelessly, using a sscanf with no length limit, permitting a
>   buffer overrun.